# How update a Azure Website via FTP transfer

Tags: azure, ftp

My requirement is to transfer files like DDL's and config files to the Azure Website from my local system.

I have gone through links and have followed following steps :

- Open FTP_Server_name_from_Publish_profile
- Supplied User name and password and Able to connect
- Cd Site\wwwroot
- put "Some_File"

Getting following error:

> 200 PORT command successful.
>   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.

When I am trying to connect via WinSCP client and transferring files via GUI it is working fine.

Also, I tried the above steps for transferring files to the sample FTP servers, and it is working Fine.

Let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you ask for. Do you want to automate an update of Azure WebSite using script? You claim you followed some steps. But using what software?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you ask for. I assume you want to automate an update of Azure Website.

As you have succeeded using WinSCP GUI, you can do the same using WinSCP scripting. The WinSCP script would look like:

```
open ftps://user:mypassword@waws-prod-am1-234.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/
put C:\myjob\* /site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/type/name/
exit
```

For details see [Automating WebJob Update](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_webjob_sftp#deploying_auto) in WinSCP documentation.

Comment: Can we do the same thing via "ftp.exe" provided by Windows.

Comment: My Requirement is when we checkin any changes to the WEBAPI project which is Hosted as Azure WebSite. TeamCity builds that project to some location I need to transfer all the files from that Build location to the Azure Website using FTP.

Comment: Where do you plan to run your FTP code? On the TeamCity server? On the Website? Or on yet different machine?

Comment: From the Team City Server machine. But I also want to test it from my local development machine.

Comment: Actually you cannot do this using `ftp.exe` as it does not support TLS/SSL encryption and Azure WebSite requires that.

Comment: But actually yesterday I was able to do that using FTP.exe , Earlier it was not working because of my office network. But when I tried it from home transfer of files was successful.